# How to set null to foreign key column in OneToMany relationship, Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 classes: User and Company.

```
User
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}

Company
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public List<User> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
}
```

I need when I delete Company to set foreign key company_id as null in User table. How could I do this?

Comment: user.setCompany(null); Company.getEmployees().remove(emp); ?

Comment: I think this could do with CascadeType or smth. by I don't know how.

Comment: it has "something to do with CascadeType" if you want to cascade the delete, but then bearing in mind that your question doesn't mention wanting to do that, then no it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the relationship you describe would be created with a `constraint` on the Foreign Key that references the `User` entity. This is so you can't set it to `null`. If you set it to null, it becomes an `orphaned` row, which makes for a bad database.

If, on the other hand, you need the two entities to persist separately from their joins, then your relationship is not as you are describing it.

It seems that in this case Companies and Users (Persons?) both need to exist without necessarily being joined. I would suggest a new entity, something like `Employment`. It would effectively act as a `join table` in the sense that it has both `Company` and `User` id's, but it could also have more information such as `startdate`, `enddate`, and `current employer`.